# position element on top of another

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, css-position

i am looking for a jquery plugin that will let me absolutely position one element on top of another.

This plugin should understand **scroll offsets**, and **borders**. bonus points if it looks right on both **ie** and **firefox**.

bonus point if it repositions itself on window **resize**.

does something like this exist, or am i stuck rolling my own?

Comment: Couldn't this just be done with clean CSS?  When you say "on top of" do you mean positioned above or literally one covering the other?

Comment: yep, i mean covering another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe the official [jquery ui position utility](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) will do it for you